# Redux com múltiplas instâncias da aplicação

Tags: react, redux

> Se o Redux mantém um único estado dos componentes e eu tenho múltiplas
>   instâncias da aplicação sendo usadas por múltiplos usuários, isso
>   significa que os usuários irão visualizar o mesmo estado nos
>   componentes? Como resolver esse problema quando queremos na verdade
>   que cada usuário visualize dados relativos ao seu acesso de usuário?

Eu desenvolvi [essa aplicação](https://github.com/giuliana-bezerra/instalura). Eu abri a aplicação com 2 navegadores diferentes (Firefox e Chrome). Se eu logar no Chrome (user: alots, senha: 123456), no Firefox a aplicação vai logar também. Como ambos os navegadores apontam para o mesmo servidor, estão apontando também para o mesmo estado, por isso, se eu modificar o state em um navegador, isso tem efeito no outro. Ou seja, a aplicação vai ser renderizada com o mesmo estado para diferentes usuários! Esse é o problema que estou questionando, como separar esse estado para diferentes instâncias do sistema.

Comment: Eu uso o `Vuex` que é equivalente ao `Redux`. A ideia principal dessas funcionalidades são compartilhar o estado entre os componentes onde a comunicação se torna difícil. Tenho usado o Vuex em uma aplicação hibrida(aplicativo) e isso que você acabou de relatar não tem ocorrido comigo.**Isso significa que os usuários irão visualizar o mesmo estado nos componentes?** Não deveria! Teria que entender melhor o seu problema.

Comment: Aqui tá normal. Eu sei que é antigo, só deixando aqui pra quem ver essa pergunta e não perder tempo.

Comment: Não use `onEnter` no `react-router@4`